# Can't get Result to show with HTML Forms and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm trying to get my results to show up in the text box inputs as per my assignment but I can't get them to show up at all. The math isn't showing up at all so my big issue is that I can't get the code to show up in the box.

```js
document.querySelector.("#buttonS").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (document.querySelector("#gallons").reportValidity()) {
    let gallons = document.querySelector("#gallons").value;

    if (document.querySelector("#quarts").checked) {
      quartsTotal = gallons * 4;
      document.querySelector("#quartsResult").placeholder = `quartsTotal`);

  } else if (document.querySelector("#pints").checked) {

  } else if (document.querySelector("#cups").checked) {

  }

}

});
```

```html
<form id="bakimg">
  <input type="number" step=".01" min="0" id="gallons" required><label for="gallons">  How many gallons of milk do you have?</label>
  <br>
  <br>
  <label for="conversion">Which conversion would you like?</label><br>
  <input type="radio" value="quarts" name="gallonsC" checked><label for="quarts">Quarts</label>
  <input type="radio" value="pints" name="gallonsC"><label for="pints">Pints</label>
  <input type="radio" value="cups" name="gallonsC"><label for="cups">Cups</label>
</form>
<br>
<button type="button" id="buttonS">Submit</button><br>
<h1>Results</h1>
<br>
<input type="text" id="quartsResult" placeholder=""><label for="quartsResult">Quarts</label><br>
<input type="text" id="pintsResult"><label for="pintsResult">Pints</label><br>
<input type="text" id="cupsResult"><label for="cupsResult">Cups</label>
</div>
```

Comment: `"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '('",`

Comment: document.querySelector.("#buttonS") --> document.querySelector("#buttonS")

Comment: All of these simple errors you could have found yourself using the [browser debugger](https://javascript.info/debugging-chrome).

Comment: @yogi i am still very new to this and i don't understand everything in the console. that's why i asked for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your syntax and make the following changes:

- Check the browser console for errors and use the appropriate syntax:

```js
document.querySelector.("#buttonS")
```

should be written like this:

```js
document.querySelector("#buttonS") // No . after querySelector
```

- Check the extra parentheses:

```js
document.querySelector("#quartsResult").placeholder = `quartsTotal`); // <-- Remove the closing parens
```

- Add the proper IDs to the HTML input elements (quarts, pints, cups):

```html
<input type="radio" value="quarts" name="gallonsC" checked id="quarts">
<input type="radio" value="pints" name="gallonsC" id="pints">
<input type="radio" value="cups" name="gallonsC" id="cups">
```

- Remove the backticks in order to use the variable value (otherwise quartsTotal is still a string):

```js
`quartsTotal` -> quartsTotal
// Perhaps this is what you meant:
`${quartsTotal}`
```

Good luck with the assignment!